# Make It Easier to Access Tag Wiki From Mobile

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki

As it stands, it's difficult to get to a tag wiki from the mobile site (you can always enter the URL into the browser, of course, if you happen to know the URL scheme). If you click on a tag, you're taken to a page listing all questions with that tag. Perhaps there could a link to the wiki right after the part that says "Questions tagged `<whatever>`"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the reason is that there actually [isn't a mobile optimised version of the tag wiki pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150317/is-the-tag-info-page-not-available-on-phone-version).

There are a couple of feature request posts asking for this to be improved/made available, I think the best thing would be to go and post on and vote for those questions:

- [View tag wiki excerpt on tag page on mobile site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101113/)
- [Can we get a “learn more…” link to tag wikis on the mobile site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161668/)

Comment: Ah, so my search-fu let me down, because I did look on both meta-SO and here before posting. I've voted for the first question you linked, because I like that design better.